# How to get the unmatched column name Using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Match multiple column in different sets and update an another column with the all the unmatched column name separated by ,  For Eg:

Update the result column with the unmatched column name

Input Data:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D   Col E  Col F

Ind      Aus    Chi     Ind      Aus
Aus      Usa    Nz      Aus      Uk
Chi      Ind    Chi     Ind     
Ber      Ger    Sri     Ber      Nz
Ind      Aus    Chi     Chi      Aus
```

Expected Output:

```
      Col F
Col AD, Col BC Unmatched
Col BC Unmatched

Col BC Unmatched
Col AD, Col BC Unmatched
```

Script i have been using so far:

```
if Col E != " ":
  if Col A  != Col D  && Col B != Col C:
     df['Col F'] = "Col AD, Col BC Unmatched"
  else:
     df['Col F'] = "Matched"
```

Not able to understand how to perform this

Comment: I think there's a typo in your last snippet. What should be "Col E" appears as "col E" in the first if statement. Can you check if that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make an example.

You got something like

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  f  e  b  a  d
1  c  b  a  c  b
2  f  f  a  b  c
3  d  c  c  d  c
4  f  b  b  b  e
5  b  a  f  c  d
```

Then you want to see if, for example, cols `A == D` and cols `B == C` and put the result in a new column as a string, right?

If this is the case, we can do a for loop

```
for idx in df.index:
    unmatch_list = []
    if not df.loc[idx, 'A'] == df.loc[idx, 'D']:
        unmatch_list.append('AD')
    if not df.loc[idx, 'B'] == df.loc[idx, 'C']:
        unmatch_list.append('BC')
    # etcetera...
    if len(unmatch_list):
        unmatch_string = ', '.join(unmatch_list) + ' Unmatched'
    else:
        unmatch_string = 'ALL MATCHED'
    df.loc[idx, 'MATCHES'] = unmatch_string
```

that gives

```
   A  B  C  D  E           MATCHES
0  f  e  b  a  d  AD, BC Unmatched
1  c  b  a  c  b      BC Unmatched
2  f  f  a  b  c  AD, BC Unmatched
3  d  c  c  d  c       ALL MATCHED
4  f  b  b  b  e      AD Unmatched
5  b  a  f  c  d  AD, BC Unmatched
```

Comment: what would be the case when both the cases matches, How this can be executed in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure about your question, as you state that you want **all** unmatched columns in the new column but your *expected output* seems to be something else.

If you only want some columns check, then you can do as @Max Perini shows. In addition to it you should check with an *if* statement if the *unmatch_list* is empty and then apply "Matched" to the new column.

If you really want **ALL** unmatched columns if **Col E != ''**, you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "Col A": ["Ind", "Aus", "Chi", "Ber", "Ind"],
    "Col B": ["Aus", "Usa", "Ind", "Ger", "Aus"],
    "Col C": ["Chi", "Nz", "Chi", "Sri", "Chi"],
    "Col D": ["Ind", "Aus", "ind", "Ber", "Chi"],
    "Col E": ["Aus", "Uk", "", "Nz", "Aus"],
    "Col F": ["", "", "", "", ""],
})


for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Col E'] != '':
        match_str = ""
        for j, valA in enumerate(row):
            for k, valB in enumerate(row[(j+1):-2]):
                if valA != valB:
                    match_str += f"Col {chr(ord('A')+j)}{chr(ord('A')+(k+j+1))}, "
        if match_str == '':
            df.loc[idx, 'Col F'] = 'Matched'
        else:
            match_str = match_str[:-2] + " Unmatched"
            df.loc[idx, 'Col F'] = match_str
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'Col F'] = ''
```

yielding:

```
  Col A Col B  ... Col E                                             Col F
0   Ind   Aus  ...   Aus  Col AB, Col AC, Col BC, Col BD, Col CD Unmatched
1   Aus   Usa  ...    Uk  Col AB, Col AC, Col BC, Col BD, Col CD Unmatched
2   Chi   Ind  ...                                                        
3   Ber   Ger  ...    Nz  Col AB, Col AC, Col BC, Col BD, Col CD Unmatched
4   Ind   Aus  ...   Aus  Col AB, Col AC, Col AD, Col BC, Col BD Unmatched
```